# How to command regedit to go to Google URL Via Chrome

Tags: boot, google-chrome, windows-vista, windows-registry

I was having another problem, and tried a "solution" that not only didn't fix the problem - but created a new one. The original problem I solved (I can't remember what it was), and I can't remember how to get back to a regular start-up while using Chrome. Instead of getting Google on Chrome, I go to a non-existent URL at http://xn--disk-cache-size%3D10000000-qf2psj/ I've already checked the Control Panel and browser settings, and they say to go to www.google.com - so that isn't the problem.

My recollection is that I did something in "regedtit" in the command window. How do I reset regedit to get Chrome to startup at google.com again?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can't imagine registry plays any role in browser startup tabs. I just Changed my Google Chrome startup tab, and it updated this file:

```
%localAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences
```

To modify it, Press `Windows+R` to open `run`, paste this line, then press enter:

`notepad "%localAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"`

Now press `Crtl+F` to find the string `startup_urls`. You can find the startup address(es) right next to it. If it's `http://xn--disk-cache-size%3D10000000-qf2psj` then change it to `https://www.google.com` and save the file.

If it doesn't fix the problem, or you still believe registry keys are the culprit, you can find and delete Google Chrome registry keys under:

```
HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome
HKLM\Software\Google\Chrome
HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Google\Chrome
```

Comment: Thank you - how do I start it up with notepad?

Comment: Press `Windows+R` to open `run`, paste this, then press enter: `notepad "%localAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"`

Comment: I really appreciate your assistance. I get up to Crtl+F and when it says, "Find What" and I enter startup_urls. Then it says that it can't be found. I also tried using the same "Run What" window to find the incorrect URL that keeps coming up and it didn't find that either. I'm running Vista - which I know is old, but it's all I've got right now.

Comment: If you can't, please open `"%localAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` copy and attach `Preferences` file to your post, or upload it somewhere.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to open the location you referenced above, but don't understand what you mean, or where you mean for me to copy or attach "Preferences."

Comment: Dear Chavez, please after you opened the folder above (which you already did), upload the file `Preferences` found in that folder, to an upload service (for example, Dropbox, Box, OneDrive, GoogleDrive, Mega,...) then paste the link of the uploaded file, here in comments so I can download it and check what's wrong, ok?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem for a while now myself. Just fixed it. Don't screw with the Registry, you don't need to. Here's how I fixed it on my computer.

Go to the Chrome icon on your desktop. If you don't have an icon on your desktop, then go to your local drive on your computer (usually C:)>Program Files>Google>Chrome>Application>Chrome Icon. Whichever way you got to the Chrome icon, right click on it. Go to "Properties" and left click on it. If it's not already open, left click on the "Shortcut" tab. Now you see where it says "Target" and then a box with a bunch of stuff in it? Left click inside the box, hit the end button on your keyboard. You probably see something like this in the box: "D:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"http://xn--disk-cache-size%3D10000000-qf2psj/

That's what mine said. Just highlight everything after "D:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

So basically you highlight http://xn--disk-cache-size%3D10000000-qf2psj/
in the box, then hit backspace or delete, which should leave you with something like this "D:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" click apply, then OK. Close Chrome if it's open and restart it. Should work perfectly now every time, and take you to the Google home page or whatever page you specified in your Chrome settings.